# Calling a PHP page from HTML page

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML page "mcqs.html" and from that page I want to go to the index.php page which is in php. In HTML `<a href="about.html"> About </a>` works fine.

But this doesn't seem working when I include a link for a .php page `<a href="about.php"> About </a>` . Need some guidance to solve this problem.

Comment: I have HTML page "mcqs.html" and from that page I want to go to index.php page. In Html we did <a href="about.html"> About</a> but this is not working for php <a href="about.php"> About </a>. What should I do?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: What does not work about `<a href="about.php">About</a>`? Does the about page load?

Comment: where do you actually want to go? index.php or about.php?

Comment: Jefree Sujit any php page.

Comment: cale_b yes page loads.

Comment: Then what does not work?  Please expand the question - its unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the extensions of the file.
Example if you have mcqs.html then you should write

```html
<a href="mcqs.html">Page Title</a>
```

make sure the the file is one directory in mcsql.html and index.html..
If not,you should up the directory until you reach the file using ../ (It's mean up one directory)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes i am using right extension.

Comment: Please use full words, not text-like (use "you" not "u")

Comment: @cale_b thanks for the suggestion I have correct it.Still new in this forum. Sorry

Comment: @Alii are mcsql.html and index.php in same directory.

Answer (score 0):

For running a php file you must have installed a server stack such as Wamp (Windows) or Lamp (Linux) and after that move your folder to the www folder and then try this in your html file and this should work.

```
<a href="about.php">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken your question, its a pretty simple things. Just use following link-

Add following code in **mcqs.html** page.

```
<a href="index.php">Go to Index Page</a>
```

Hope, will work perfectly for you.

Make sure that the server that you are using is supported by PHP